# Buy and sell in same blocknumber?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

Hello everybody I need your help.

I know this is possible but I think only with **Solidity**.

Actually, to sell tokens the fastest possible, I use the function `balanceOf` only after BUY so if it returns value = 0, it makes a bool if value > 0, it sends my SELL function.

I know it's possible to buy and immediately after sell tokens in **Solidity**, but how to do with **Javascript** or **Python** ?
Do I need to send a signed Tx? I don't know is there a tutorial please?

Comment: Sorry for the question, but what are you trying to do? Something like a front run?

Comment: Im trying to buy and sell fastest possible in solidity with 2 différent Tx , can you help me ?

Comment: I think you already thought about it but my idea is: 

1 - Get AmountsOut.
2 - Send Buy Tx (swapETHfor **ExactTokens**) with a little bit higher Gwei.
3 - At the same time (or with a little delay) send Sell Tx (swap**ExactTokens**ForETH) with normal Gwei...-

The main idea is send two transactions at the same time but "force" the buy tx to approve first.

Comment: Ok im gonna try it : I have create function Buy and function Sell(Get amount at start of function ) in my solidity contract im gonna call buy and sell in same time in my JAVASCRIPT with différents gas, i am comming back

Answer (score 1):

Make one function in your smart contract that buy, check if balance > 0, and if yes, sells the token.

Here is an example of pseudo code

```
 function buyAndSellInOneFunction(uint256 erc20Amount) public  {
       DexContract.buy(erc20Amount);
       uint myBal = erc20.balanceOf(address(this));
       if(myBal > 0){
           DexContract.sell(myBal);
       }
    }
```

That will buy and sell in one block

Then call that function from your javascript backend/script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what im seaching for if i follow your step it sell after some block ? Im seaching a way to buy and sell in same block in few time .. if i call function balanceOf i need wait the token come into my account and sell that take like 3 sec its too long there is a way to buy get the amountOut and immediatly sell the token amount ..

Comment: I have edited my comment to include some pseudo code, let me know if that helps.